# Laravel 5.1 change password functionality

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, bcrypt, change-password

I need a change password functionality for my laravel app.
I have created this view:

```
{!! Form::password('old_password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Then in my controller I'm checking to see if the value entered for the `old_password`is the same as user's current password.

```
if(bcrypt($request->old_password) !=$user->password) return redirect()->back()
```

The problem is that the above condition will always be true. This mins even if the user enters a valid password this condition will return true!
Why it is so?
By the way I'm hashing the password in my user model:

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bcrypt()` generates a random salt each time. In order to check passwords, I should use Hash::check().

[Link to docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/hashing)

Example in docs:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text-password', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Comment: You are checking if the passwords doesn't match, remove `!` for passwords match.

Answer (score 4):

There is a helpful Authentication function called `Auth::validate($credentials)` where you pass the `[username, password]` or `[email, password]` combination. This will check whether the provided `$credentials` is valid or not without logging the user in.

So in your `AuthController` you would check:

```
...
$credentials = [
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'password' => $request->get('old_password'),
];

if(\Auth::validate($credentials)) {
    // TODO: Old password is correct, do your thing
    // Change password and login, OR
    // Send them to the login page
}

return redirect()->back()->withError('Incorrect old password');
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found a better solution.